# Difference between bit times and milli seconds

Tags: computer-networks

The propagation delay between two links is 200 bit time .....i want to know what is the difference between 200 bit time and 200 mill seconds

Answer (score 1):

The propagation delay is time it takes to transfer one bit from sender to receiver.
200 ms would be such time, for Bit Times it is the duration of given bits in the medium, the first bit of a header reaches the receiver before the last bit was transmitted by the source (here also given 200).